# Why Not Use Instance Objects Instead of ThreadLocal in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local

I was reading [this](https://dzone.com/articles/painless-introduction-javas-threadlocal-storage) article about ThreadLocal objects in Java in an attempt to understand why and when they would be used. In the article, I came across an example meant to demonstrate how to use ThreadLocal. It was a class that was supposed to be a transaction manager, and it used a static transactionID variable that was used throughout the class. In order to make the class thread safe, it used a ThreadLocal for the transactionID:

```
public class TransactionManager {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> context = new 
    ThreadLocal<String();

    public static void startTransaction() {
        //logic to start a transaction
        //...
        context.set(generatedId); 
    }
    public static String getTransactionId() {
        return context.get();
    }
    public static void endTransaction() {
        //logic to end a transaction
        //…
        context.remove();
    }
}
```

My question is, why not just make the transactionID an instance variable instead of making it static in the first place? That way you wouldn't need to use a ThreadLocal variable.

Comment: Because *then* you'd need a separate `TransactionManager` per thread, and you couldn't call `TransactionManager.startTransaction()` statically.

Comment: @chrylis Is there a downside to having a seperate `TransactionManager` per thread, such as overhead?

Comment: As opposed to globally? Per-thread is usually *necessary* to ensure correct processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference would change on some scenarios, but let's try some things:

I will assume the outline of the example is something like "We are executing several steps in some process and we want to generate a transactionID to identify one execution of the process. All those steps run in the same thread for any given execution"

In this case, the difference would be that if you make it an instance variable (yes, you can do it), you will have to create your transactionId and propagate the TransactionManager instance across all the layers and classes you might need it as a parameter, making your methods signature dirtier than need to be (Imagine you have one StepExecution interface and all steps implements that interface, but not all steps might need to access the transactionID, you will then have one useless parameter mixed in your method signature)

Not only that, ThreadLocal will guarantee you that the value you are accessing is the one you generated on the same thread, preventing "leaks" of information among threads making it perfectly thread safe.

Answer (score -1):

> ...and it used a `static transactionID` variable that was used throughout the class. In order to make the class thread safe, it used a `ThreadLocal` for the `transactionID`

That basically is *the* use-case for `ThreadLocal` in a nutshell:  You have some body of non-thread aware code that you want to make thread-safe, but it uses one or more static variables.  If it makes sense for each thread to have its own independent copy of the static variable, then you just pop in a `ThreadLocal`, and problem solved!